# How do I Add Android support into TensorFlow and React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, deep-learning, expo, tensorflow.js

When I follow instruction given by https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-for-detecting-objects-in-an-image-on-mobile-devices-7d5b2e5621f9

I get next error on Android devices when try to detect obj.

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s See https://fb [dot] me/react-warning-keys for more information.%s,

Check the render method of `CocoSsdScreen`., ,
    in RCTView (at CocoSsdScreen.js:125)
    in CocoSsdScreen (at SceneView.tsx:98)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:89)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:88)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:125)
    in RCTView (at BottomTabView.tsx:42)
    in SceneContent (at BottomTabView.tsx:127)
    in RCTView (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:44)
    in RCTView (at ResourceSavingScene.tsx:27)
    in ResourceSavingScene (at BottomTabView.tsx:122)
    in RCTView (at screens.native.js:132)
    in ScreenContainer (at BottomTabView.tsx:106)
    in RCTView (at BottomTabView.tsx:105)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at BottomTabView.tsx:104)
    in BottomTabView (at createBottomTabNavigator.tsx:41)
    in BottomTabNavigator (at BottomTabNavigator.js:19)
    in BottomTabNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:98)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:89)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:88)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:125)
    in RCTView (at CardContainer.tsx:199)
    in RCTView (at CardContainer.tsx:198)
    in RCTView (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:526)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at Card.tsx:508)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandler.native.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:502)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at Card.tsx:498)
    in RCTView (at Card.tsx:492)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:164)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:497)
    in RCTView (at Screens.tsx:70)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:490)
    in RCTView (at Screens.tsx:48)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:388)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:433)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:431)
    in RNCSafeAreaView (at src/index.tsx:28)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:428)
    in RCTView (at StackView.tsx:427)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:82)
    in StackNavigator (at App.js:53)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:288)
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:64)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:63)
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at App.js:52)
    in RCTView (at App.js:50)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:26)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:40)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:101)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:63:8 in console.error
- node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
- node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:172:36 in warningWithoutStack
- node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:612:32 in warning
- node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1723:14 in validateExplicitKey
- node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1745:28 in validateChildKeys
- node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:1962:24 in createElementWithValidation
* screens\CocoSsdScreen.js:171:12 in render
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:13042:21 in finishClassComponent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:12970:4 in updateClassComponent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20459:25 in beginWork$$1
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19370:24 in performUnitOfWork
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19347:39 in workLoopSync
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18997:22 in renderRoot
* [native code]:null in renderRoot
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18709:28 in runRootCallback
* [native code]:null in runRootCallback
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5642:32 in runWithPriority$argument_1
- node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:643:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5638:22 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5627:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18556:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7799:17 in classComponentUpdater.enqueueSetState
- node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js:325:31 in Component.prototype.setState
* http://packager.dt-ayw.anonymous.objects-detection.exp.direct/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:145260:31 in _callee2$
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:274:30 in invoke
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:145:19 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:146:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:194:17 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:458:30 in callImmediates
* [native code]:null in callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:407:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:143:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:142:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Running application on FIG-LX1.
Exception Error:  [TypeError: Network request failed]
Exception Error:  [TypeError: Network request failed]
```

I tired to fix in next way at file `/screens/CocoSsdScreen.js line 125`

changed in

```
<View key={index} style={styles.welcomeContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>
```

but it didn't work. Could anyone please help me.

p.s. Git repo is at:
https://github.com/yzzhang/machine-learning/tree/master/mobile_apps/objects_detection

Comment: It looks like its connected to this  
Local fetch not working in android tfjs-react-native 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/3186 

try {
      const response = await fetch(imageAssetPath.uri, {}, { isBinary: true });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        alert(error);
    }

Comment: What do you mean by saying it didn't work? What error did you get after assigning key to View?

Comment: The error wasn’t connected to it how much i see error happens because fetch not working in android.